# Checking file attributes in python

Tags: python

I'd like to check the archive bit for each file in a directory using python. So far i've got the following but i can't get it to work properly. The idea of the script is to be able to see all the files that have the archive bit on.

Thanks

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
import os , win32file, win32con
from time import *
start = clock()

ext = [ '.txt' , '.doc' ]

def fileattributeisset(filename, fileattr):
    return bool(win32file.GetFileAttributes(filename) & fileattr)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('d:\\Pruebas'):
    print ("root", root)    
    print ("dirs", dirs)
    print ("files", files)
    for i in files:
        if i[ - 4:] in ext: 
            print('...', root, '\\', i, end=' ')
            fattrs = win32file.GetFileAttributes(i)
            if fattrs & win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE:
                print('A isSet',fattrs)
        #print( fileattributeisset(i, win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE)) 
    print ('####')
```

EDIT: all files appear to have the archive bit on, doing 'attrib' shows that all files have no attribute bits on.

Comment: When you say it doesn't "work properly", what happens?

Comment: -1: no traceback or error messages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file list returned from os.walk are not fully qualified paths, so when you call

```
win32file.GetFileAttributes(i)
```

it can't find the file and returns an error code; which happens to be -1. So the operation

```
fattrs & win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE
```

is always true.

You need to join the root to the filename so that GetFileAttributes will succeed:

```
fattrs = win32file.GetFileAttributes(os.path.join(root, i))
```

Also, when you are checking the extension, it is probably better to use `os.path.splitext(path)` to retrieve the extension rather than relying on them be 3 characters long as you do.