# How to check the read/write status of storage media in python?

Tags: python, windows-xp, filesystems

How can i check the read/ write permission of the file storing media? ie assume i have to write some file inside a directory and that directory may be available on read only media like (cd or dvd)or etc. So how can i check that storing media ( cd, hard disk) having a read only or read write both permission.

I am using windows xp os.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [os.access(path, mode)](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.access) function. It should be much more portable than the win32api function. Though, I have no experience with it on non-POSIX systems.

On the other hand, why don't you just try to write the file and handle exception appropriately?

Comment: "It's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission."

Comment: Does not work correctly on read-only optical media: `>>> os.access("d:\\", os.W_OK) --> True`

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
from stat import *

if S_IMODE(os.stat(dir_name)) & S_IWRITE != 0:
```

is more portable, if not necessarily more readable.

Comment: but `os.access()`, as Jacek notes, is better still

Comment: This works in the case where os.access failed, read-only optical media: `>>> stat.S_IMODE(os.stat("d:\\").st_mode) & stat.S_IWRITE
 --> 0`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `win32api.GetFileAttributes` method.

P.S. also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659847/checking-file-attributes-in-python)